# What is the purpose of the Stark theme?

Tags: theming, 10

Claro is for administration, Olivero is general, but what is Stark for?

> An intentionally plain theme with no styling to demonstrate default Drupal’s HTML and CSS. Learn how to build a custom theme from Stark in the Theming Guide.

If it's plain and with **no styling**, how does it demonstrate Drupal's (HTML) and **CSS**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme's [online documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/themes/stark-theme) explains further:

> The Stark theme is provided for demonstration purposes; it uses
> Drupal’s default HTML markup and CSS styles. It can be used as a
> troubleshooting tool to determine whether module-related CSS and
> JavaScript are interfering with a more complex theme, and can be used
> by designers interested in studying Drupal’s default markup without
> the interference of changes commonly made by more complex themes.
>
> Users should not use it as a base theme as future core updates may
> break your theme.

In addition there is [an issue to further discourage](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2854576) its use as a base theme.

Comment: The quoted documentation is outdated. Now you shouldn't use Stable either. If you want to use Drupal's default HTLM and CSS set the base theme to false. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3309392

Comment: One of us should modify this answer.

Comment: I shortened the quote to include only true information.

Comment: I am confused, should stable and classy not used at all, only stark then?

Comment: "Which base theme should I use" is a different question.